# How is the subspace identified?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Linear Algebra class, I was learning about vector spaces and subspaces but can't quite grasp the concepts. We were given the following:

1. $w = \{(a,b,c) \in R^3 : a = 1\}$
2. $w = \{(a,b,c) \in R^3 : a = 0\}$

We were told that (2) is a subspace, while (1) is not because (1) is "not closed under addition". What does that mean?

Comment: "not closed under addition" means that if you add two elements, the result isn't necessarily in the set

Comment: also note:  a subspace must contain the zero vector (though not every subset that contains the zero vector is a subspace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set 1 is "not closed under addition" because vectors in this set are of the form $\left [ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
y\\
z\\
\end{array} \right ]$.  If I add any two of these together I get the result

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
a\\
b\\
\end{array} \right ] + \left [ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
c\\
d\\
\end{array} \right ]\;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
2 \\
a+c\\
b+d\\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

and this doesn't belong to the set since our first entry isn't 1.  The second set is "closed under addition" since vectors in this set are of the form $\left [ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
y\\
z\\
\end{array} \right ]$ and adding any two of them yields:

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
a\\
b\\
\end{array} \right ] + \left [ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
c\\
d\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
a+c\\
b+d\\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

We see that addition in this set preserves the first entry remaining zero, guaranteeing that adding two vectors in this set keeps you in the set.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, setting any of the variables to be a non-zero constant makes it not a subspace because they will be "not closed under addition" and setting any variable to some x \notin {0,1} will make it "not closed under multiplication". Is that correct?

Comment: That's pretty much correct.  Vector spaces/subspaces need to have an identity element (i.e. a zero vector).  In other words, there should be a vector $\vec{0}$ such that for any other vector $v$ you have $\vec{0} + v = v$.  If you force every vector in your set to have a fixed nonzero entry, it eliminates the zero vector as a possibility thus violating the defining characteristics needed for the vector space.